# Структура андроид приложения

Tags: android

Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах, простую структуру андроид приложения. Конкретно меня интересует, как реализовать вычитку/апдейт/запись в БД( не технически, а структурно). Как я понял, делать запросы к БД напрямую из приложения - это плохо и неправильно. Как тогда правильно,  поднять вебсервер, сделать бекенд и меняться информацией средствами HTTP запросов или JSON? То есть по сути, если это просто веб приложение, то в ответ браузеру мы шлем разметку страницы + контент, здесь тоже самое, только получатель приложение и обрабатываем только контент?

Comment: Не знаю, то ли это что вы искали, по крайней мере здесь есть все ответы на ваши вопросы: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

Answer (score 0):

Очень сумбурный вопрос... Надеюсь я правильно понял что вы хотите услышать.

Основной поток в андроид отвечает почти за все, в т.ч. за прорисовку пользовательского интерфейса. Соответственно, если вы прямо из него сделаете запрос к сети или бд, который будет выполняться 10 сек, то все эти 10 секунд пользователь будет видеть абсолютно статичную картинку и убьет приложение как зависшее. Если запросы будут выполняться по 200мс, то у пользователя начнется эпилептический припадок от постоянных подлагиваний. На самом деле если вы попытаетесь обратиться к сети из основного потока, то программа вылетит, но все равно все медленные операции надо выполнять в других потоках. Сюда относятся бд, подгрузка данных и изображений из файлов и т.п.

Когда вы делаете клиент-серверное приложение, то у вас 2 основных пути: общение с сервером по сокету и общение по http(s) через api. Первый используется в довольно специфичных ситуациях, почти наверняка вам нужен api. Возвращать api должен только данные, отображение должно быть описано в приложении. Если вы пришли из веба, может вас устроит [этот](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/450506/) вариант